# Should we remove event listener before destroying objects

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, does the following create a memory leak

```
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.setAttribute("type","button");
button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
button = null;
```

Do I have to remove the event listener first?

**EDIT**

Update to my question, I *think* that because I'm not actually adding this element to the DOM, then it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @Amadan, Please see the edit. Unless my understanding is incorrect, I've not added this element to the DOM. The element exists in memory only (I think)

Comment: Whether or not you add it to the DOM is not an issue; whether you still hold the reference to the element or not is.